# How to pass date values from a csv file using jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a CSV file that passes the values of http request parameters. It works as desired except for the field that is a date value. It fails not recognizing it as a date. Now I can type it in ex. 2019-04-05 or assign it to a user define variable ex. MyDate = ${_time(date format)} or myDate = 2019-04-05 that works. Any ideas?

I have searched but can't find the right solution for this scenario. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Please share the request. What is JMeter sending with request and what is the response

Comment: Correction- I would like to use a time function in the field via the CSV file to get the current date. When I tried to use the user defined variable it doesn't work. Ex. MyDate = ${_time(date format)}.

Comment: The request parameter looks like catagory = ${name} catDate=${MyDate}. Jmeter request sent  looks like https://website/catagory ="value"?catDate="${MyDate}"